# Multiple bar (mean and Standard Deviation) in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a multiple error bar (mean and standard deviation) of value of 5 species by 5 transects in ggplot2. I tried but did not find appropriate strategy. 
Sample code of value, transect and species includes following:

```
value<-as.integer(runif(1000, min = 0, max = 5)) ## values of 1000 observations)
    transect <- sample(1:5, 1000, replace=T) ## transect ID
    x<-c("SpeciesA","SpeciesB","SpeciesC","SpeciesD","SpeciesE")
    species<-rep(x, 200)
    data<-data.frame(cbind(value,transect,species)) # species ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with them all on the same plot. Good things to play around with would be `geom` and `position` in `?stat_summary`

```r
value <- as.integer(runif(1000, min = 0, max = 5)) ## values of 1000 observations)
transect <- sample(1:5, 1000, replace = TRUE) ## transect ID
x <- c("SpeciesA", "SpeciesB", "SpeciesC", "SpeciesD", "SpeciesE")
species <- rep(x, 200)
data <- data.frame(cbind(value, transect, species)) # species ID

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(species, value, colour = transect, group = transect)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = 'errorbar', position = 'dodge')
```

[image]